# Google Maps - reverseGeocodeCoordinate won't print address in Singapore

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

I'm working on app which use Google Map, and trying to print address. However, it doesn't work when I move my map around Singapore. I got the coordinate, but the location isn't printed. Below is my code. Already tried with

```
let lines = address.lines
```

then print

```
self.locationTF.text = lines.joined(separator: "\n")
```

but the address still not appeared. My code is working when I moved the map around Malaysia and Indonesia, but not in Singapore. Is anyone knows why this happens?

```
// Implement Geocoding - show street address
func reverseGeocodeCoordinate(_ coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    self.vc.locationTF.unlock()

    let geocoder = GMSGeocoder()
    print("COORDINATE: ", coordinate)
    geocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate(coordinate) { response, error in
        guard let address = response?.firstResult(), let sublocality = address.subLocality, let locality = address.locality, let state = address.administrativeArea else {
            return
        }
        self.vc.locationTF.text = sublocality + ", " + locality + ", " + state
        print("LOCATION: ", sublocality + locality + state)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
            self.vc.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your guard will only let your code continue if all properties `sublocality`, `locality` and `administrativeArea` are not nil. When you use it in Singapore one of those properties might not be available and your code returns before printing location.

Comment: @LeoDabus thank you. I just noticed it now. it works when I only let lines = address.lines without other properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guard will only let your code continue if all properties sublocality, locality and administrativeArea are not nil. When you use it in Singapore one of those properties might not be available and your code returns before printing location.

Comment: thank you again! btw, is there any way to declare other properties of the address to print only the sub locality, locality & administrativeArea (if available) after I declare only the lines in guard?

Comment: I've updated the answer from the link above to handle CLErrors and print additional info